# Finding angle of sector which forms a cone

Tags: calculus

To find the angle where it is in rad,
am I right to say that $10*(angle\ in\ rad)=2\pi*(radius\ of\ cone)$

[image: Cone]

Answer (score 1):

The radius of the sector is the lateral height $l$ of the cone, and the length of the arc is the circumference of the base, that is, $2\pi r$. So the angle you ask for is
$$\theta=\frac{2\pi r}{2\pi l}=\frac rl$$
measured in radians.

Comment: Why do you divide by $2\pi l$ instead of just $l$?